# Why is Virtual Box not copying data to disk?

Tags: virtualbox

Virtual box not installing disk. Once I try to detect disk as I tried before, it pops up a question to proceed installation to unclean target. On pressing 'yes', it shows that the failing step is installing the system. On pressing 'no', it shows that it will not install to unclean target. I have tried to install several times? Still no go.

Comment: Perhaps try a new virtual hard disk with a different size.

Comment: What are you trying to install? What is the precise error message when you select "yes"? Since the installation process seems to choke on an "unclean" disk, give it a clean disk. By the way, this is most likely not a problem of VirtualBox, because Virtualbox doesn't care for clean or unclean disks. It's a problem of your installation program.